# User Data backup to Google Drive under "Backup" category

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I was doing some R&D regarding backing up user data to Drive. User data meaning dbs or their own created content using the app. I want this to basically persist the data in case user changes their device or drops it in the ocean or whatever.

I googled it and found the [Application Folder API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder) where it uses hidden folder. I checked my own Drive and found something interesting. Some apps are using the Application Folders to store their data; quite normal.

[image: Normal apps]

But some apps for example, WhatsApp, has its data backup listed specifically under the "Backup" category.

[image: WhatsApp backup]

I searched for the difference and didn't find anything. I was wondering how to get the backup under "Backup" category which seems to be the perfect option. It also provides extra info and options when some backup is selected.

Any idea? What could be the difference between these two? How to get backup under the "Backup" category?

**UPDATE:** I think Drive provides special treatment to WhatsApp backups, and hence they are shown separately along with the phone data backup. I'm just guessing this after reading [this recent news](https://www.theverge.com/2018/8/16/17705194/whatsapp-google-drive-backups-free). Please provide some clarification on this.

Comment: U got the solution??

Comment: Nope.. not yet.

Comment: Please post the solution if u got any.. even im searching.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone got solution

Comment: Any solution for this yet?

Comment: Come on, it's been 3 years now. Has anyone got anything? Don't shy, tell us :P

Comment: No solution to this yet ? 
I implemented user data backup in google drive and it is listed under drives folder and not under backup folder. I tried changing drive space, that has some issues.

Answer (score 6):

For Android, try using the [Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html).

> Auto Backup preserves app data by uploading it to the user's Google Drive account, where it is protected by the user's Google account credentials. The amount of data is limited to 25MB per user of your app and there is no charge for storing backup data.
>
> Users can see a list of apps that have been backed up in the Google Drive app under **Settings -> Auto Backup for apps -> Manage backup**.

Comment: This is not what I want. This is about the App Data, and I'm specifically asking about User Data. In short I want the backup mechanism like WhatsApp.

Comment: How does google app backup has more than 25 mb limit for whatsapp?